# Inner approximation of a Lebesgue Measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is we want to show there is a sequence of closed sets, $\{C_k \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $C_k \subseteq E\ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, $C_k \uparrow C $ as $k \rightarrow \infty$, $\lambda(E \setminus C) = 0$.

So what I was going for was this: Since $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, $E^c$ is a measurable set.  There is an open set $O$ so that  $E^c \subseteq O$, and  $\lambda(O \setminus E^c) < \epsilon$. The thing that is troubling me is how to come up with the sequence. I was trying to come up the sequence like this:

$$ \{O_k \} \mbox{ is   a  sequence defined as }  E^c \subseteq O_k \subseteq O_{k+1} \subseteq O. $$

Then, I was going to define the sequence of closed sets as $\{ C_k\} = \{O_k^c \}. $

Am I on the right track here? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you spell out the relationship between $\epsilon$ and $k$, you will be very close.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I wrote a full answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In your approach, you are using the regularity of the Lebesgue measure: for any Lebesgue-measurable set $A$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $O$ such that $A \subset O$ and $\lambda(O \backslash A) < \epsilon$. Note that this is a deep result, and that it is not true in the other direction (think $A = \mathbb{Q}$).

Now, you actually pretty much proved the other direction with closed sets, by taking complements: there also exists a closed set $F$ such that $F \subset A$ and $\lambda(A \backslash F) < \epsilon$.

Therefore, if you take $A = E$ and $\epsilon = 1/k$, it gives you a sequence of closed sets $(F_k)_{k \geq 1}$ such that for all $k$,
$$
\lambda(E \backslash F_k) < \frac1k \to 0.
$$
It is not exactly the sequence that you want since it is not increasing. But then if you take
$$
C_k = \bigcup_{i = 1}^k F_k,
$$
you get what you need. Note that $C = \bigcup C_k$ may not be closed though.